# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'transform'

Tags: python, django, numpy, transform

AttributeError at /turboai/turboAI/jaaiparameters/
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iV4Ww.png)

> ```
> def transform_data(df, cols, scaler, n_days_past=120):
>
>     n_cols = len(cols)
>
>     # df to np array
>
>     np_arr = np.array(df.values.flatten().tolist())
>
>     np_arr = scaler.transform([np_arr])
>
>     np_arr = np_arr.reshape((np_arr.shape[0], n_days_past, n_cols))
>
>     return np_arr
> ```

Comment: Provide some code/data to reproduce the issue

Comment: did you initialise the `scaler` object anywhere? `scaler = StandardScaler()`

Answer (score 1):

The caller pass None value in your `transform_data` method for `scaler` thats why you are getting the above error

If you are not sure about the value in scaler you can update your code like below where you first check the `scaler` object and then perform the operation on top of it.

```
def transform_data(df, cols, scaler, n_days_past=120):
    n_cols = len(cols)
    np_arr = np.array(df.values.flatten().tolist())

    if scaler:
        np_arr = scaler.transform([np_arr])
    np_arr = np_arr.reshape((np_arr.shape[0], n_days_past, n_cols))
    return np_arr
```

Comment: Value Error:   cannot reshape array of size 5880 into shape (5880,120,49)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69738583/what-is-type-error-cant-pickle-weakref-objects
here is my other question  that is very helpful for understanding the code